# How can I use SQL Server to determine the length of a full-text indexed varbinary field?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing, varbinary

I have stored a number of binary files in a SQL Server table. I created a full-text-index on that table which also indexes the binary field containing the documents. I installed the appropriate iFilters such that SQL Server can also read .doc, .docx and .pdf files.

Using the function DATALENGTH I can retrieve the length/size of the complete document, but this also includes layout and other useless information. I want to know the length of the text of the documents.

Using the iFilters SQL Server is able to retrieve only the text of such "complicated" documents but can it also be used to determine the length of just the text?

Comment: In addition, I use a Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (which isn't much), there is no way to query document properties via FTS. I would get the word count before inserting the document into the database, then insert the count along with it, into another column in the table. For Word documents, you can use the Document.Words.Count property; I don't know what the equivalent mechanism is for PDF documents.

Comment: This is indeed what I have done. Although I did not use VSTO. I used a c# script to grab the document from the database, used the appropiate iFilter to retrieve the text of a document in any file format.